# Not able to generate Wsdl2Apex

Tags: wsdl2apex

I gave up in this task. I want to generate wsdl2apex for below xml but not able to generate. please help. I already tried removing import xml and adding its content from after  tag. But I am getting one issue after another. Can you please guide me how to generate Apex for below wsdl.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jh32r0yn9olqw03/soap.xml?dl=0

Length of wsdl is very big so attaching it to dropbox

Comment: Many services offer REST/JSON APIs that can be a lot easier to program against in Apex than WSDL APIs. Suggest you check that possibility.

Comment: but in my case customer don't want to use rest API so trying this. actually before this task also I got stucked with another wsdl but that time I escaped by using REST. Below was my previous problem
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G0000005YmZQAU

Comment: There are two problems with the WSDL approach: 1) when the generation tools fail you need a lot of insight into XML Schema; 2) the Apex tools are pretty poor compared to those in more mainstream languages. That means the WSDL approach can be hard (=expensive) or impossible to accomplish. JSON forces simplicity, and Apex's support for JSON is good and there are tools like https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/. Explain this to your customer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full solution for you, but I can get you started. First, there's no support for `xsd:import`. You must manually import those definitions into the WSDL, *or* configure your tool to generate a WSDL that does not use `xsd:import`.

Second, you cannot access `localhost` in Apex Code. Make sure you configure your tool to use your public, externally available domain name or IP address.

Third, you must use the "document literal wrapped" WSDL type. If you can't generate this WSDL type, you won't be able to use WSDL2Apex.

Fourth, make sure that you are using only supported WSDL data types:

- xsd:anyURI
- xsd:boolean
- xsd:date
- xsd:dateTime
- xsd:double
- xsd:float
- xsd:int
- xsd:integer
- xsd:language
- xsd:long
- xsd:Name
- xsd:NCName
- xsd:nonNegativeInteger
- xsd:NMTOKEN
- xsd:NMTOKENS
- xsd:normalizedString
- xsd:NOTATION
- xsd:positiveInteger
- xsd:QName
- xsd:short
- xsd:string
- xsd:time
- xsd:token
- xsd:unsignedInt
- xsd:unsignedLong
- xsd:unsignedShort

There might also be additional issues with your WSDL, but you need to fix these problems to start with. Please read through [SOAP Services: Defining a Class from a WSDL Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) and all its sub-categories for additional information. They include a sample WSDL; if you can model your WSDL after this sample, you should be fine.

Typically, when I have issues with a WSDL, I try importing a smaller version of it, with just one schema/type, one message, one operation, one port, and one binding. Once you get the small one to work, you can then introduce the newer, more complicated types.